# Pergo over existing Pergo?

Tags: flooring

Does anyone know if you can install new Pergo over existing Pergo?  I have installed Pergo or similar type products, in many rooms of my home.  Some have been directly on a new wood subfloor, some over existing ceramic tile.  Have never had any issues--this would be my first attempt at putting it over an existing Pergo floor.

Thanks for  any insights.

Comment: Would you put on the foam cushion between the two Pergo layers?

Comment: Hi Jim:  I would be using the Pergo that already has the underlayment attached to it.

Comment: Pergo is easy to remove even the older glued type removal of the old material would be better than having to recut the trim in my opinion. When I see layer after layer of flooring or roofing I think hack job just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I was always told not to install a floating floor over a floating floor.However I have done this several times in my house without any problems.One concern would be if both floorings have a sponge backing,the floor might feel excessively spongy.In hindsight I wouldn't have done this because I had to re-undercut the doorways and raise all of the base.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  What I actually may do is do a test run of it---that is lay some down and see how it reacts---fortunately don't have to contend with any door clearance issues, and would be removing the base.